# Including unicharambigs in the [lang].traineddata file (Tesseract)

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm facing a problem in training the Tesseract OCR for Kannada font (Lohit Kannada and Kedage), when it comes to numerals.

For example, 0 is getting recognized as 8 (and ನ  as ವ).
I needed help in including the unicharambigs file (the documentation on Github describes the format solely).My output.txt file has not changed,despite including the unicharambigs file.

Suppose [lang] corresponds to kan, will the following command include the unicharambigs file in the kan.traineddata file?

`combine_tessdata kan.`

Incase it doesn't, I'd appreciate any help regarding how to proceed with the same.

Comment: Hi @Sukriti, Is it solved by unicharambigs method or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer not knowing which version of [`tesseract`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tesseract) and `kan.traineddata` you're using.

You can unpack the `kan.traineddata` to see the version of `kan.unicharabigs`  included in it and then recombine it after editing the file.

see https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/combine_tessdata.1.asc for command syntax

- Use `-u` option to unpack:

  - `-u .traineddata PATHPREFIX` Unpacks the `.traineddata` using the provided prefix.
- Use `-o` option to overwrite `ucharambigs`:

  - `-o .traineddata FILE…`​: Overwrites the specified components of the `.traineddata` file with those provided on the command line.

Please note that https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/blob/master/kan/kan.unicharambigs seems to be a copy of `eng.unicharambigs`

Comment: You can modify https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-attachments/tesseract-ocr/issue-801/comment-6/kan.DangAmbigs.txt to unicharambigs format.
See https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#the-unicharambigs-file or the format of the unicharambigs file.